# Running a scheduler on more than one machine

Tags: java, db2, locking, scheduling

I have a Java service which creates x games in the future every y seconds (calculating start time and end time for each of them) and inserts them into a DB2 table. The code basically looks for the end time of the last created game, if it exists and is not in the past, and uses it to create future games. Otherwise, it uses the game duration (same for all games) and the current time to create the new games.

This service will run on several machines at once, so there is a risk that the check for the last game is not accurate. One solution would be to lock the whole table, but this doesn't scale well. Any ideas of more efficient handling of this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 (and most enterprise database vendors) have proper locking mechanism in place for highly concurrent workloads to satisfy the database ACID properties. You should not need to worry about placing explicit locks on your tables yourself.

In DB2, an isolation level determines how data is locked or isolated from other processes while the data is being accessed. Following are details about the different isolation levels:

```
UR: Allows an application to access uncommitted changes of other transactions.
CS: Locks any row accessed by a transaction of an application while the cursor is positioned on the row. This lock remains in effect until the next row is fetched or the transaction is terminated.
RS: Locks only those rows that an application retrieves within a unit of work. It ensures that any qualifying row read during a unit of work is not changed by other application processes until the unit of work completes.
RR: Locks all the rows an application references within a unit of work.
```

You can read more on the limitations for each isolation level in this article so you can choose the most appropriate level for your query:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1107db2isolationlevel/